# Is blender a good choice for creating illustrations/demonstrations?

Tags: animation, physics, workflow

I want to create educational content to youtube and my blog. That includes topics i would like to had myself when i started with but where so hard to understand. So instead of writing text which tends to be more boring the longer it is, i would really love to illustrate the most things with animated illustrations ... but not in the way that looks like a cheap 90s animation we all know from our beginning of the beginning in blender ... realistic would be good but in the end the effort is not reasonable for a one man show.

What cames to me in mind intstead are these well known low poly illustrations that are explaining things in an really entertaining way ... for example:

a low poly character laying with head on his desk, a questionmark appears over his head ... he has an idea ... something appears here and there .. the desk fly's out of the screen, a plant appears and scales bigger ... the camera zooms to the plant and shows something that gets explained more detailed ... then zoom out, the plant disappears, animated like a exploding balloon etc ...

The advantages with low poly in general i hope to have are

- low render times due to low poly scenes
- easier (or at least acceptable) general production times
- realistic renders doesnt matter
- since my topics are in the same branch over and over again, i could reuse the most of my models and scenes for future videos

I am not completely new to blender and basically i like blender and love to play around with it.  But after my tough developing learning curve the last two weeks i really ask me if blender is the right choice doing this educational stuff including also some basic physics or is it not really made for this?

An frustrating example: I spend hours to figure out while one object does not has any effect colliding with the other one ... pushed hundreds of buttons, without any success ... 
Also I had the imagination that some easy looking effects might be not that hard to implement ... done once its easy to reuse ... but yeah ... even simple scaling and appearing animations doesn't seem really simple in blender

what i mean: you lose the focus on what you want to do after you struggle around doing details five hours ...

and the next question i am asking for would be "how to organize all these animations, that may repeat for many many objects and projects over and over ... how to manage different scenes from one an the same setup?"

Sure ... might be not a big deal for a pro ... but is there maybe anything out there, that does the thing in a more efficient way or should i stick to blender anyway? Are there any good resources?

I don't fear the effort learning blender but i don't want to waste time at things, that does in the end not fit to what i wanted to achieve originally

Can somebody that has/had similar goals give any advices to me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi. This question is broad, asks multiple questions and is opinion-based - all of which are reasons to close this question as off-topic. Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to improve your question. If you think you can improve it you can use the [edit] link below it.

Comment: So okay, where is the section to ask opinion based questions? Thats what i really like to have as an answer here ...

Comment: [Blender Artists](https://blenderartists.org/) is a better place for discussions. This site is a Q and A site for specific questions with specific answers.